# Why is ListAppend non destructive, while ArrayAppend and StructInsert are both destructive?

Tags: coldfusion

I just spent almost an hour trying to figure out an issue with having a list that would always return an empty string. I was using ListAppend just like one uses ArrayAppend or StructInsert, but apparently ListAppend works differently. What, if any, is the reasoning behind having ListAppend work differently from everything else?

```
<cfset ListAppend(list, item)>
```

list = ''

```
<cfset ArrayAppend(array, item)>
```

array[1] = item

```
<cfset StructInsert(struct, 'key', item)>
```

struct.key = item

Comment: I had this same experience and question yesterday.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does arrayAppend return true and listAppend return the list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138709/why-does-arrayappend-return-true-and-listappend-return-the-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly because  a list is just a big [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Unlike arrays and structures, Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), meaning they cannot be changed. To "append" a new value, you need to create an entirely new String. Arrays and structures are mutable. So you can modify them "in place".

Comment: I had this question yesterday. Thanks for such a clear answer.

Answer (score 5):

Lists in ColdFusion are just Strings and strings in ColdFusion (and Java) are immutable. They cannot be changed. So ListAppend() must return the a new string with the value instead of modifying the existing string.

```
<cfset newList = listAppend(oldList, "New Value") />
```